# User cannot see TFS2010 test results in VS2010

Tags: mstest

I have a few lists of tests that I setup for a project that builds to a website. I have a bunch of unit tests and integration tests that runs before deploying the site. I have one user that clicks on the failed build in Build explorer but the Test results(that I can see-all test) that appears below that is empty.

If I click on it I can see a complete list of tests that passed as well as the test that failed. In the "Test Results" window at the bottom there is a drop down list to choose the(it looks like environment??) and when they choose "System@SERVERNAME SERVERTIME" it does not show the list that I can see if I am logged in. It seems to be a permission issue but where?

Thank you
Jack